# Using-declared type declaration conflict

Tags: c++, c++20

Should the declaration of a type alias result in a conflict when it shares the same name as some member type that was introduced from a base class with a using-declaration? I would expect the following code to result in a declaration conflict, however, Clang seems to be fine with it.

```
template<typename>
struct b {};

template<typename T>
struct d : b<T> {
    // using b<T>::t;       // all fail
    using typename b<T>::t; // ok on clang
    using t = d;
};
```

[Live example](https://godbolt.org/z/jb7z9vWfb)

Comment: This is one of those questions where, regardless of what the answer is, you should avoid this scenario. The fact that it is not immediately obvious what the right thing to do means that the right thing to do is to just not have these conflicts.

Comment: With templates, you sometimes have to instantiate to get errors. Have you tried defining a variable whose type is `d<int>::t`? (Looks like that's when clang will start complaining, even if you adjust things so that `b<T>::t` actually names a type.)

Comment: Suggestion: add the following at the end of your example. This instantiates the template, and the result passes on clang (because both `t` definitions match?) but fails on gcc. This might be a better example to ask about: `template<> struct b<int> { using t = d<int>; };

int main() { d<int>::t x; (void) x; }`

Comment: @NicolBolas I agree, and I wasn't sure if wanted to post this question because it might not lead anywhere. Clang's inconsistent behavior was somewhat bothersome to me, as I don't see why the use of the optional `typename` would make a difference here. I'm hoping someone could quote some standardese so this issue with Clang could be addressed properly.

Comment: @JaMiT I don't really see how that example is different, since GCC fails with the same error.

Comment: @303 The difference is that the templates are instantiated. But, you do you. It's not like I mentioned that finishing your current example with something like `template<> struct b<int> { using t = int; };  int main() { d<int>::t x; (void) x; }` would cause clang to produce an error. Maybe the language standard does call for clang giving an error with just your current code. (I don't know.)

Answer (score 2):

```
template<class T>
struct base {
  void method() {}
  using type = int;
};

template<class T>
struct derived : base<T> {
  using base<T>::method;
  using base<T>::type;
  using type = int;
};
```

Clang will fail to compile this, because it presumes `base<T>::type` is a **method name** not a type, like `base<T>::method`.  So it finds that the symbol `type` is defined as both a method and a type.

```
template<class T>
struct derived : base<T> {
  using base<T>::method;
  using typename base<T>::type;
  using type = int;
};
```

it will compiles this.  If you add in:

```
template<>
struct base<char> {
  void method() {}
  using type = bool;
};
```

then do:

```
using some_type = derived<char>::type;
```

it will complain about the type conflict of `base<char>::type` (which is `bool`) and `derived<char>::type` (which is `int`) at this point.

[Godbolt link to both compilers failing at different spots](https://godbolt.org/z/hafTr9sPq).

So here are my observations:

1. clang requires `using dependent_declaration` to be `using typename dependend_declaration` when it is supposed to be a type, and otherwise assumes it is a method (or something else?) being brought into scope.

gcc lets types be brought into scope using `using` without the `typename` disambiguator.

If gcc is following the standard here, the standard has a bug.  The removal of disambiguators was supposed to only occur when there was no syntactically correct result that wasn't a type in that spot.

2. Clang doesn't diagnose type conflicts for a given name until the name is evaluated later.  This kind of delayed error can happen either when a program is ill-formed, no diagnosis required; or here, often in the body of templates otherwise illegal code is allowed to pass until you use it.

To complete this answer, I'd have to do a pass of the standard to see if this is an ill-formed, ndr case, or a delayed instantiation case, or if clang is in error here.

I'm pretty sure, however, that defining the same name as the same type in multiple using/typedef declarations is fine.  The only thing that I could see as being questionable is that this is two different *kinds* of using declaration; one of them is the "using name from another scope" and the other is a "using to replace typedef".

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a Clang bug.

If you have an *alias-declaration* and a *using-declaration* in the same *namespace* scope, and they both declare the same name as an alias to the same type, then Clang, GCC, and MSVC all accept it. For example

```
namespace N {
    using I = int;
}
using N::I;
using I = int;
```

The relevant rule is [namespace.udecl]/12:

> Since a *using-declaration* is a declaration, the restrictions on declarations of the same name in the same declarative region (6.4) also apply to *using-declarations*.

And the restrictions referred to are found in [basic.scope.declarative]/4:

> Given a set of declarations in a single declarative region, each of which specifies the same unqualified name,
>
> - they shall all refer to the same entity, or all refer to functions and function templates; or
> - exactly one declaration shall declare a class name or enumeration name that is not a typedef name
>   and the other declarations shall all refer to the same variable, non-static data member, or enumerator,
>   or all refer to functions and function templates; in this case the class name or enumeration name is
>   hidden (6.4.10).

Importantly, the entity referred to by `using N::I;` is the type `int`. It is not the typedef name `N::I`, because a typedef name is not an entity; the type it denotes is.  At least, that's what [basic.pre]/3 says. So that means both declarations refer to the same entity, namely the type `int`.

But when class scope is involved:

```
struct b {
    using t = int;
};

struct d : b {
    using b::t;
    using t = int;
};
```

We see that [Clang, GCC, MSVC all reject](https://godbolt.org/z/Gj53Gzexh).

One might think this is due to the fact that you're not allowed to declare the same class member twice inside the class, [class.mem.general]/5:

> A member shall not be declared twice in the *member-specification*, except that
>
> - a nested class or member class template can be declared and then later defined, and
> - an enumeration can be introduced with an *opaque-enum-declaration* and later redeclared with an *enum-specifier* .
>   [*Note 3*: A single name can denote several member functions provided their types are sufficiently different (12.2). — *end note*]

But [class.mem.general]/2.3 says that a *using-declaration* doesn't declare new members of the class. The only thing it can do is redeclare `b::t`. Clearly, you're allowed to have a typedef named `t` in the base class and another typedef named `t` in the derived class. So why is this rejected? It all goes back to [namespace.udecl]/12 and [basic.scope.declarative]/4. The *using-declaration* causes `b::t` to be redeclared in the declarative region of the derived class `d`, where `d::t` is also declared.

And—this is the crucial part—`b::t` and `d::t` do *not* denote the same entity, because according to [basic.pre]/3, **a class member is an entity**. So, this is not like the namespace or block scope case, where the two declarations both denote the same entity, namely the *type*. Here, the *using-declaration* refers to the *member* `b::t` while the *alias-declaration* refers to the *member* `d::t`. These aren't the same entity, so [namespace.udecl]/12 is violated.

Only when `b` and `d` are made into templates, Clang seems to lose the ability to diagnose this, even after `d` is instantiated. There doesn't seem to be any good reason for this.

If `d<T>::t` is made a different type from `b<T>::t`, Clang still won't diagnose it when `d<T>` is instantiated, but will diagnose it only when `d<T>::t` is referenced. That also seems like a Clang bug; typedefs and *using-declarations* are not subject to deferred instantiation. They are instantiated when the class is instantiated.

(In C++23 the description of name lookup will change significantly, but the actual content of the rules won't change much. I don't think there is anything in the working draft that would materially change the above analysis; the terminology is just different.)

Comment: "**a class member is an entity** - do you mean a **type is an entity**?  As far as I can tell `b::t` is a type not a class member.  Wait, 7.1.3 says typedefs are class members.

Comment: [dcl.typedef]/2 says that `using A=B;` is semantically equivalent to `typedef B A;`  And `typedef A A;` is strongly implied to be illegal under [dcl.typedef]/3 and [dcl.typedef]/4 within a class.